# How do you name a C# method of a controller class which is a Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, naming-conventions

A REST API deals with resources, so the practice is to name the API as noun (the name of the resource) and Http method (verbs) should reflect the action the API performs.
I am trying to understand whether that also applies to naming the method of the controller class. I am using Web API 2 which would be self hosted using OWIN.
What should be the naming convention for a controller method in C#?

For example if I need to get products by Id, I understand the uri would look something like /api/products/id. What about the controller method? Should the method name include a verb?

```
Route("api/products/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Product> FindProduct(string id) { ... }
```

Comment: the method name is okay, actually this is not exposed in client level, so no  worries

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "GetProduct" would be the most obvious here. FindProduct sounds like "more work", for example if you had criteria other than the ID. Your mileage may vary on this - just my take.

In general, you'll probably want to name these methods just like you would any other method. I'm not sure I can reasonably think of any good use for method names that don't use a verb - commonly first in the name. Methods, by their very nature, do things, and you'd be hard pressed to call them something meaningful without verbs. *edit: also To, As, etc.*

Comment: I agree about your comment on method name that its not meaningful without verbs. What is generally practiced in this case? I don't think I am the first one getting into this ;-)

Comment: @tyrion I've not really had vast amounts of experience with different projects in ASP.NET, but the only thing I've ever seen done is to, for the purposes of naming methods, "forget" that they have anything to do with controllers, Web API and routes, and just go ahead and call them whatever seems logical, following the same conventions as any other place. After all, there's nothing special about those methods themselves.